# bootstrap fixed navbar vertical alignment issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I added a Bootstrap fixed bottom navbar in my ASP.net project master page, it had a logo and a copyright text (To make it simple I borrowed Microsoft logo). 
I wanted them in one row so I applied .navbar-left style to their parent , worked, however, I found the text is top aligned, I want it has a vertical center alignment, how to achieve that? Thanks.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" id="footer">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
    <li><img src="http://c.s-microsoft.com/en-us/CMSImages/mslogo.png?version=856673f8-e6be-0476-6669-d5bf2300391d" alt="MSTF Logo"/></li>
    <li><p>&copy; 2015 Microsoft. All rights reserved</p></li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tz783rkn/5/

Answer (score 0):

add this code inside img tag:

`style="float:left; margin-right:7px;"`

For example:

```
<img style="float:left; margin-right:7px;" 
src="http://c.s-microsoft.com/en-us/CMSImages/
mslogo.png?version=856673f8-e6be-0476-6669-d5bf2300391d" 
alt="MSTF Logo"/>
```

see this: http://jsfiddle.net/tz783rkn/7/
from there you can set the margin-top of second `<li>` to make it nice to see

UPDATED:
http://jsfiddle.net/tz783rkn/9/

Comment: Thanks @gkol. I think the key is not inline style of <img>, since .navbar-left already has "float:left" defined, key is the margin-top of text.

Comment: Any difference? I prefer to not using inline style. And this hard coded margin-top solution is not very perfect: on my real project the logo picture is not so big, if I set to 8px, text looks centered but it also increases the height of whole navbar, if I set to 4px which doesn't increase the height of navbar, the text becomes not center-looking again.

Comment: I use class="text-center" to handle this. in the last link, I use the class.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to accomplish what you are trying to do:

First: If your logo size is predetermined, then you could add a class, lets call it "copyright-text", to the list element containing the text. We could then style the element and give it some margin on the top (and on the left) to give the appearance that it is positioned in the center.

```
.copyright-text {
    margin-top: px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Here is a fiddle showing that approach: http://jsfiddle.net/tz783rkn/8/

Second: The second approach sets the display of the surrounding container to display as a "table", and then create an inner "div" element with the display set to "table-cell". This allows you to use the "vertical-align" CSS property which lets you position elements in the middle of a parent element, similar to how you can in tables. This requires restructuring your HTML a little and adding some additional classes or inline styles:

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" id="footer">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
    <li class="table-container">
        <div class="tabel-cell-container">
            <img src="http://c.s-microsoft.com/en-us/CMSImages/mslogo.png?version=856673f8-e6be-0476-6669-d5bf2300391d" alt="MSTF Logo"/>
            <p class="copyright-text">&copy; 2015 Microsoft. All rights reserved</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {
    min-height: auto;
}
li.table-container {
    display: table;
}
.tabel-cell-container {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.copyright-text {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Here is a fiddle using the table display approach: http://jsfiddle.net/tz783rkn/16/

It's difficult to see the result with such a small area, so you can exaggerate the list item height to see how it positions the child elements in the middle of the parent element as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tz783rkn/17/).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Josh! Your second solution looks great! But there is still a minor flaw. I have updated the logo picture to reflect the real size of the logo in my real project. As you can see, the copyright text actually is not *really* vertical centered, even you already specified vertical-align to middle, what is the root cause of this? Is it because of font's baseline and decent? P.S. here is my updated version with your second solution: http://jsfiddle.net/tz783rkn/24/

Comment: The reason it doesn't look centered is because the text in the image isn't centered in the middle of the image. This causes the "look" of the vertical alignment to appear like its not working as intended. The only way around this is to add extra padding to the text, but because of the way we set up the vertical-align property, we would have to float the text to the right, and then add around 8px of top padding or margin to get the text to line up correctly. Here is an updated solution: http://jsfiddle.net/tz783rkn/26/

Comment: Note that using the updated solution doesn't really offer any benefit over the first solution in my answer, other than the ability to vertical-align other elements (including the image) within the parent container.